# StrongARM architecture instruction format

Tags: assembly, architecture, arm

I'm doing some research for a class on the StrongARM architecture and I have a question about how instructions are formatted. According to the documentation, it implements the ARMv4 architecture, but it also says that it uses coprocessor instructions to control the operations. I looked at the coprocessor instructions and I didn't see any type of branch or r-type instructions. So my question is, does this architecture still use the ARMv4 instructions for performing these tasks, but use the coprocessor to do the backend fetching and decoding stuff, or are there instructions for branching and r-type operations for the coprocessor that I'm missing.

Comment: Are you talking about the SA-1500 and its Attached Media Processor?

Comment: Not sure about vfp (likely) but for example the fpa floating point instructions were a coprocessor from that time period (arm not necessarily dec/intel) and were defined using floating point fields/terms but you can see how they lined up with coprocessor instructions.

Comment: I would also not assume that the strongarm is a modified armv4 I would assume it was built from scratch to implement the instruction set faster or whatever its goal was, so if it has a coprocessor interface it doesnt necessarily have to conform to arm documents for armv4.  Just like the xscale really isnt an arm either.   a little googling and it appears that for an arm core, the coprocessor has taps into the pipe, but as far as branching it isnt called out specifically although pipeline manipulation is.

Answer (score 1):

Intel bought a company that had the source code rights to the ARMv4, and the original StrongARM's were based on this, running at a much faster clock rate than the other vendor's versions of the ARMv4. It was a standalone processor as opposed to processor core logic embedded into a chip for an embedded application. Assuming that the StrongARM you refer to is still based on the ARMv4, then the co-processor has multiple purposes, depending on the configuration, such as providing a debugger interface, and memory management. Do a web search for StrongARM control registers to get a description of what features are included in the co-processor.